# Run regex on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, regex

I am trying to run a regular expression in a SQL statement to return all rows where the regex is true.

This is the regex:

```
(A1|A2|A3|A4).{0,50}(B1|B2|B3).{0,200}(word1|word2)
```

I have tried this (and variants of):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE  '%[(A1|A2|A3|A4).{0,50}(B1|B2|B3).{0,200}(word1|word2)]%'
```

The regex itself is okay, but running seems to be the problem.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: share sample data and its expected ouput

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support Regex. You have the `LIKE` expression ([LIKE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)), however, this does **not** have  same functionality as Regex; it just uses "Regex like" syntax.

Comment: As @Larnu stated, SQL Server doesn't natively support Regex, however it does provide [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) which you *might* be able to bend to your will and achieve similar results.